# Equivalent to SQL group_concat() aggregation function using Unix?

Tags: unix, zsh

In ZSH, a ZLE command can have multiple key bindings, e.g.:

```
▶ bindkey | grep accept-and-hold 
"^[A" accept-and-hold
"^[a" accept-and-hold
```

How do I produce a list from `bindkey` that aggregates all key sequences for a given command into one line?

One solution using [`q`](https://github.com/harelba/q):

```
▶ bindkey | q "select c2, group_concat(c1) from - group by c2" | grep accept-and-hold 
accept-and-hold ^[A,^[a
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using using fancier tools such as `perl`, `awk`, `sed`, `q`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some `awk` to the rescue:

```
% bindkey | awk -v zle=accept-and-hold '$2==zle{s=s" "$1};END{print zle s}'
accept-and-hold "^[A" "^[a"
```

And if you really want to have the quotes removed:

```
% bindkey | awk -v zle=accept-and-hold '$2==zle{s=s" "gensub(/\"/,"","g",$1)};END{print zle s}'
accept-and-hold ^[A ^[a
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using using fancier tools such as `perl`, `awk`, `sed`, `q`, etc.

There's not much left over… but we could use an associative array to aggregate the key sequences (value) for a given command (key):

```
b=`bindkey`
typeset -A a
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
eval "${b//(#b)([^$'\n']#) ([^$'\n']#)/a[$match[2]]+=\ $match[1]}"
print -RaC2 ${(kv)a}
```